# Dynamically create a keySelector c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I am struggling with Expression, Func &co.

I know that is possible to create expressions that allow to select one field for example

```
Select(t=>t.MyProperty);
```

is equivalent to

```
var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
var propExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExp, "MyProperty");
var convertedExp = Expression.Convert(propExp, typeof(object));
var keySelectorExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convertedExp, paramExp);
Select(keySelectorExp.Compile());
```

What I would like to achieve is

```
Select(t=> new {t.Prop1, t.Prop2})
```

or

```
GroupBy(t=> new {t=>Prop1, t.Prop2})
```

I hope it is possible.

Thanks,
Alessandro

Comment: Is it clear or should I improve my question?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are trying to do, but it is entirely unclear why. Could this problem be solved in another, less complicated way?

Comment: @ing.alfano In a project of mine, because I didn't want to emit a type as Bryce says, I ended up creating an expression of an array of strings with `Expression.NewArrayInit` and reflection over the type `T`.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comments, I realized that they might not be technically correct.  The main point was to not use an anonymous type, because even if it's technically possible, it's way way way more bother than it's worth.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it is more clear now

Comment: It should be possible, but probably isn't that easy.  I would probably temporarily hard code something to examine then debug it, examine the expression tree and then work out from that what functions you need to call to reproduce it